# How to use if/else awk to evaluate a file and extract this information?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a file like this:

```
419 I     0.3529
420 S     0.3182
421 T     0.3740
422 Y     0.3872
423 I     0.3460
424 E     0.4409
425 S     0.3182
426 T     0.3740
427 Y     0.4141
428 I     0.3460
429 S     0.3131
430 Y     0.3838
431 T     0.3939
432 S     0.3101
```

and I am trying to make an Awk program to evaluate the third column for numbers greater than or equal to 0.4. If true, take 4 characters up and 4 down in that letter (second column).  If there are multiple matches, I want one fixed-length string for each:

```
STYIESTYI
IESTYISYT
```

The first one comes because there is a match on the line numbered 424; the second is a (partially overlapping) match for the line numbered 427.  How would I approach this?

Comment: If you are not familiar with `awk`, I would suggest that you learn `perl` which  handles this sort of requirement with ease.

Comment: Why not learn awk instead since awk also handles this sort of requirement with ease AND it's what the OP asked for AND it comes as standard on all UNIX installations AND its syntax doesn't inspire people to create cartoons like http://www.zoitz.com/archives/13?

Comment: @ed-morton Personally I have never understood why some people don't like perl.

Comment: Personally I neither like it nor dislike it, I'm sure its great for whatever it is people use it for, but for text manipulation you may as well stick with a standard UNIX tool that does the job extremely well.

Comment: Perl has been installed on every Unix system I've used in the last twenty years.  That's my last word on the topic.

Comment: Perl hasn't been and still isn't installed on several of the UNIX systems I have used in the past 33 years so wrt availability YMMV. Mainly though, as I understand it, perl does text manipulation plus a lot of other stuff (shell-like functionality best I can tell) and for text manipulation I find awk to be extremely clear, simple, efficient, and robust so I'm not tempted to use perl for text manipulation while for the "other stuff" so far I haven't personally come across a need for it but again YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    tgt = (tgt=="" ? 0.4 : tgt)
    cxt = (cxt=="" ?  4  : cxt)
    bef = (bef=="" ? cxt : bef)
    aft = (aft=="" ? cxt : aft)
}
$3 >= tgt { hits[++numHits] = NR }
{ chars[NR] = $2 }
END {
    for (hitNr=1; hitNr<=numHits; hitNr++) {
        for (lineNr=(hits[hitNr]-bef); lineNr<=(hits[hitNr]+aft); lineNr++) {
            printf "%s", (lineNr in chars ? chars[lineNr] : "")
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
STYIESTYI
IESTYISYT
```

Note that this will behave sensibly if the line with the 3rd field >= 0.4 is closer than 4 lines to the start and/or end of the file - make sure to test those conditions with any potential answer as they are common rainy day cases for this type of problem that people providing potential solutions often forget to cover.

For example, try all potential solutions with this input file and see if you get the output you expect:

```
$ cat file1
421 T     0.3740
422 Y     0.3872
423 I     0.3460
424 E     0.4409
425 S     0.3182
426 T     0.3740
427 Y     0.4141
428 I     0.3460
429 S     0.3131
430 Y     0.3838

$ awk -f tst.awk file1
TYIESTYI
IESTYISY
```

or if you get missing output lines or lines with leading/trailing blanks or other undesirable chars or something else.

Note also that you can change the target value from 0.4 to something else, and you can change the number context lines to print before and/or after the the matched line just by setting command line args, e.g.

To print 5 lines of context before and after 0.37:

```
$ awk -v tgt=0.37 -v cxt=5 -f tst.awk file
ISTYIEST
ISTYIESTY
ISTYIESTYIS
TYIESTYISYT
YIESTYISYTS
STYISYTS
TYISYTS
```

To print 1 line before and 2 lines after 0.34:

```
$ awk -v tgt=0.34 -v bef=1 -v aft=2 -f tst.awk file
IST
STYI
TYIE
YIES
IEST
STYI
TYIS
YISY
SYTS
YTS
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much! I am studing this code to learn more about awk! And this works like a charm!!! very good. Will be very useful for me learn more about awk!

Comment: Good, also get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. If you have any other awk book throw it away as it's outdated at best.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk    '{a[NR]=$2; v[NR]=$3>0.4} 
   v[NR-4]{for(i=NR-8;i<=NR;i++) 
              printf "%s", a[i]; 
           print ""}' file

STYIESTYI
IESTYISYT
```

If your file is big, a rolling window might be a better solution.

UPDATE: As per @Ed Morton's comment, the script always expects that there will be 4 trailing lines after a match.  If not so, special END block need to be added to handle the dangling lines.

```
$ awk    '{a[NR]=$2; v[NR]=$3>0.4}
   v[NR-4]{for(i=NR-8;i<=NR;i++)
              printf "%s", a[i];
           print ""}
      END{for(i=NR-3;i<=NR;i++) 
             if(v[i]) 
                 for(j=i-4;j<=i;j++) 
                    printf "%s", a[j]; 
          print ""}' file
```

Comment: Try that after deleting 2 lines from the end of the posted sample input file and you'll find it only prints one line of output, nothing is printed for the 2nd match.

Comment: It works very well. Thank you alot. I will use this for learn more about awk. Thank you! 
How can I make a rolling window?

Comment: The 2nd version of the script with the input I suggested will only print up to the matching line, it won't print the values after it.

Answer (score 1):

How is this?  Keep a track of the last four characters and print them off on a match.  Then set `num` to count off the next four characters.  Note the use of `printf` rather than `print` to avoid an automatic newline.

```
// {if ($3 > 0.4) {printf "%s", v0 v1 v2 v3 ;
                   v0 = v1 = v2 = v3 = "";
                   num = 4} 
    if (num > 0) {
        printf "%s", $2;
        num = num -1;
    } else { v0 = v1; v1 = v2; v2 = v3; v3 = $2; }
    }
```

Comment: How I use awk with this script?
What is the // in the begining of the first line?

Comment: You would say `awk '// { if ($3 > 0.4) .... }' filename` although the `//` is probably completely unnecessary (it's a regex, but it matches every line, so it's not doing anything, and can be omitted).  You could also save this in a text file and pass it in with `awk -f scriptfile.awk inputfile`.

Comment: However, this only copes with a single match at a time, so isn't compatible with your updated requirements.

Comment: @tripleee No it copes with multiple matches, but you get a single string for overlapping sequences contrary to the updated requirements.

Comment: My bad, that's indeed correct.  My apologies for cutting a corner there.

Comment: I will try to make it ouput separated strings and I post here what I tried

Comment: You threw me with that `//` too -  I thought you were trying to use a C++ style comment! It definitely obfuscates the code so IMHO you should get rid of it.