# Adding constant values using awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have requirement to add constant value to 4th column if value is less than `240000`. The constant value is `010000`. I have written command but its not give any output. Below is sample data and script. Please help me in this.Thank in advance.

**Command :**

```
awk  '{
  if($4 -lt 240000)
    $4= $4+010000;
 }' Test.txt
```

**Sample Data :**

```
1039,1018,20180915,000000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,010000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,020000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,030000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,240000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,050000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,060000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,070000,1,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,080000,0,1,A
1039,1018,20180915,090000,2,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,241000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,240500,0,0,A
```

Comment: You forgot to `print`.

Comment: And you forgot to set input/output field separators to comma

Comment: And `-lt` is bash comparision, not awk. And 010000 is octal representation of decimal 4096.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk  '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                 # input and output field separators
{
    if($4<240000)                    # if comparison
        $4=sprintf("%06d",$4+10000)  # I assume 10000 not 010000, also zeropadded to 6 chars
        # $4+=10000                  # if zeropadding is not required
    print                            # output
 }' file
```

Output:

```
1039,1018,20180915,010000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,020000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,030000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,040000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,240000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,060000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,070000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,080000,1,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,090000,0,1,A
1039,1018,20180915,100000,2,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,241000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,240500,0,0,A
```

`$4+10000` not `010000` since `awk 'BEGIN{ print 010000+0}'` outputs `4096` as it is octal representation of of that value.

Comment: Its working fine. I am new in awk, which site/you-tube Chanel is better to learn. Thanks!!

Comment: I've heard [people recommend reading the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312450/how-to-use-if-else-awk-to-evaluate-a-file-and-extract-this-information#comment56426064_34317876). Also, read questions and answers posted to this community and you will learn. And don't be afraid to ask we are hungry for points. ;)

Comment: One quick question how add 1 day in column 3 in same above example. I need else part in same script to add one day for $3 if $4 < 230000

Comment: That's not a quick question but a topic for a totally new question but you'll need GNU awk and [`mktime` and `strftime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html): `20180915` -> `mktime(2018 " " 09 " " 15 " " 0 " " 0 " " 0)` add a days worth seconds and use `strftime` to reformat to `$3`.